# Configuring QoS for Lync on an iptables capable switch on a home network

Tags: networking, iptables, qos, lync, voice

My "Skype for Business" (i.e. Lync) voice conferencing tends to deteriorate when I upload a file or download a page during a conference and I can't always avoid those activites. My Windows 10 machine is connected to a linux-based (MikroTik 125-24G-1S-RM) switch that has an iptables firewall.

So what are the steps I am going to have to take to configure this? I don't need detailed instructions (I can google those), just interested in a list of the things I need to configure (from someone knowledgeable) to see if I am leaving anything out.

Comment: Is your switch just a switch, or is it a router as well? You need to be specific because your switch is normally behind a router and QoS will only work for resources within your network. QoS for Internet-intense services should be on the router so it can prioritise the traffic in/out the router to the Internet... Your switch may also be QoS capable but you'll need to look into this also.

Comment: It is only being used as a switch (it is capable of being a router - a MikroTik), and that is a good point, and something I will look into. But for now I would be happy if activities on my own windows machine didn't throttle my voice.

Comment: You might be looking for traffic shaping. In addition check the settings of programs you use to upload/download whenever they allow throttling on their own.